# Regarding dimension of space $ M_k $ when k- 12r=2 , where $ M_k $ denotes the set of all entire forms of weight k.

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

I am self studying Analytic number theory from Tom M Apostol Modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory and I have a doubt in an argument in Chapter -6 .

> Doubt is If $ M_k $ denotes set of all entire forms of weight k . Then it's a Linear Space but I don't know how Apostol deduced that dimension of $ M_k $ is [ k / 12 ] when k = 2+ 12r , [ x  ] denotes Greatest integer less than or equal to x. But why when k=2+12r  , dimension is not [k/12] +1 as when k $\neq $ 2+12r   then dimension is equal to [k/12] +1 .

Why does dimension changes when k = 2+12r . 
Can somebody please explain.

Apostol uses this formula whose image I am adding as image [image]

Comment: In some sense this is the case because there is no Eisenstein series of weight $k = 2$.

Comment: @ Paul K can you please give a more precise argument!

Comment: To make it precise with the theorem: The theorem states that $G_{k - 12r} \Delta^r$ with $r = 0,\ldots,[k/12], k - 12r \neq 2$ form a basis of $M_k$. Now, the cardinality of that basis is equal to $[k/12] + 1$ if $k \neq 2 + 12r$ for all $r = 0,\ldots, [k/12]$ and $[k/12]$ otherwise. And the "missing" basis element with $k - 12r = 2$ is exactly the the non-existent Eisenstein series.

Comment: @Paul K so argument when k = 2+12r depends upon the fact that Eisenstein Series doesn't converges when k=2

Comment: Maybe you should look into the proof the theorem. It is essentially because we have maps $M_k \to M_{k+12}$ given by multiplication with $\Delta$. This yields maps $M_k \to M_{k+12r}$ given by multiplication with $\Delta^r$. Now, $M_0$ is spanned by the constant $1$ function, $M_4, M_6, M_8, M_{10}$ are spanned by the corresponding Eisenstein series, while $M_2$ is trivial (the Eisenstein series does not converge). It is really not clear to me, where your problem actually is. To conclude the dimension, you really only have to use the theorem above which gives you a precise basis.